# Why some Makefile is missing after ./configure?

Tags: linux

I have encountered some cases that the ./configure log says:

```
...
config.status: creating xxx/Makefile
...
```

but when make fails on:

```
...
make[2]: Entering directory xxx
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `all', Stop
...
```

and xxx/Makefile is absent in the disk. Why does it happened?

Comment: You haven't given enough information to know what went wrong. You should show at least a complete transcript of your unpack-configure-make session. Preferably with an open source program so that other people can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have you manually checked that the Makefile in question is indeed there (i.e. via `ls` command or something) as the configure log suggests prior to running `make`?  You need to post a lot more information to track this problem down.

Comment: @Gilles: Herm, it is hard to reproduce. This situation would not happen every time you compile it. The two pkg I've encountered with this problem is libvorbis and bind -- all are normal autotools stuff.

Comment: @dtlussier: Hrm, the problem env is on the production machine which is not at my hand. And the problem is so hard to reproduce that I cannot introspect at that degree... ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you compile from the command-line `make` is likely to work.

But if - for instance - after `./configure` you open Eclipse and try to build the project, you may have that warning (`no all rule`).

Also, some `make` by default expect a `all` in the `Makefile` if no specific rule is provided on the command line.

I suggest you open the Makefile(s) and add the rule

```
all: build
```

after the first rule (this is usually the default: `make` takes the first rule if none provided).
`build` being that first rule - it may be different in your case.

Or you make change the `make` calls to `make <rule>`.

Comment: But the problem I encountered is that the whole Makefile file is missing ;)